# Java Stack - Modify the last element in a stack

Tags: java, stack

I have a stack of Integer in Java and I would like to know is there other way to increment "the last pushed item" by one without poped it first.

My current solution is

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);   // Increment 2 to 3
Integer last = stack.pop();
stack.push(last+1);
```

I tried the following but not working

```
Integer last = stack.peek();
last+=1;
```

I thought it would work because last is a reference to the last element in the stack and it got incremented.

Comment: What does "item by one which pop it first" mean? Did you mean to say, "without popping it first"?

Comment: `Stack` is built on top of `Vector`. You might want to use a `LinkedList` as a stack instead.

Comment: @DavidConrad yes. I meant "without popping it first".  Updated the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, the `Integer` class is *immutable*, meaning that an `Integer` object can never be modified. This:

```
last += 1;
```

is really just shorthand for this:

```
last = Integer.valueOf(last.intValue() + 1);
```

That is, it actually creates (or retrieves) a *different* `Integer` instance, whose value is one greater than the value of the previous `Integer` instance.

If you want to be able to modify the object at the top of the stack, you'll need to put mutable objects on the stack. You can create your own `IntWrapper` or `IntHolder` or `MutableInteger` class for that. (But I don't particularly recommend this.)

Comment: If you're going to go that route, probably the best thing to do would be to use a `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @DavidConrad: I feel like it's "cheating" to use an `AtomicInteger` when all that's needed is mutability, not thread-safety/atomicity. No?

Comment: I can certainly see that argument, but what I was thinking of was, why write another when there's already one in the standard library that does what you need (and then some). Plus, once you store one somewhere and you're going to mutate it, maybe that reference will escape, and you'll need the thread-safety/atomicity after all?

Answer (score 2):

with `last+=1;` you assign another object to `last`. Therefore, the stack is not manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

You need mutable long object for that, e.g. `org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableLong` or `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong`. Then you can modify it

```
stack.peek().increment();
```